# Integral of homogeneous partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

From the book "Radio Occultations Using Earth Satellites" by William G. Melbourne:

From Calculus of Variations a necessary condition for stationarity is that the ray at all points must satisfy Euler's differential equation or its integral equivalent at points of discontinuity in *n*. Euler's equation in polar coordinates is given by

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dr}\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta'} \left(n\sqrt{1 + (r\theta')^2}\right) - \frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\left(n\sqrt{1 + (r\theta')^2}\right) = 0
\end{equation}

(Note: $\theta' = d\theta/dr$)

When $n$ is a function of $r$ only, one can integrate to obtain

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta'}\left(n\sqrt{1+(r\theta')^2}\right) = \text{constant} = a
\end{equation}

---

What are the steps in performing said integral?

---

what I've tried:

\begin{equation}
\int d\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta'} \left(n\sqrt{1 + (r\theta')^2}\right) = \int \frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\left(n\sqrt{1 + (r\theta')^2}\right) dr
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta'} \left(n\sqrt{1 + (r\theta')^2}\right) = \int n \frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\left(\sqrt{1 + (r\theta')^2}\right) dr
\end{equation}

I'm stuck on the partial derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: Since I don't have the book, I'm sort of speculating. But I hope this will help you at least a bit anyway.

It looks like the action is just Fermat's principle
$$
S = \int dt = \int \frac{1}{v} ds = \int n(r,\theta ) \sqrt{ 1 + (r \theta') ^2 } dr
$$
In the above, you are parameterizing the path by $ r $, so that $ \theta $ is a function of $ r $. The $ \sqrt{ 1+ (r \theta') ^2 } dr $ is the differential line element $ ds $.
When you have an action of the form:
$$
\int L\left(r,\theta(r), \theta'(r)\right) dr
$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation, which tell you what the stationary paths are, looks like 
$$
\frac{d}{d r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'} L - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} L = 0 
$$
I don't know why he writes the partials in the way that he does, but it is not standard notation. Ignoring this difference, you can check that the Euler-Lagrange equations give what you have above:
$$
\frac{d}{d r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'} \left( n(r,\theta) \sqrt{ 1 + (r \theta') ^2 } \right) - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left( n(r,\theta) \sqrt{ 1 + (r \theta') ^2 } \right) = 0 
$$

Finally, suppose $ n $ only depends on $ r $ and not $ \theta $. Then there is no dependence on $ \theta $ at all in $ n \sqrt{1 + (r \theta')^2} $. So the term above on the right with $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta } $ goes away. You're left with:
$$
\frac{d}{d r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'} \left( n(r,\theta) \sqrt{ 1 + (r \theta') ^2 } \right) = 0
$$
which of course means that with respect to $ r $
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'} \left( n(r,\theta) \sqrt{ 1 + (r \theta') ^2 } \right) = \text{constant}
$$
In the context of classical mechanics, this is basically saying that when the lagrangian is independent of position, the momentum is conserved.

Comment: Actually, can you tell me why $\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta} f(\theta')$ is $0$?

Comment: Because $ \theta $ and $ \theta'$ are different variables! This is why it is better to write $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta } $ so that it is clear that you have a function of two variables $ f(\theta, \theta') $, and you want to take the partial derivative of the function with respect to the first argument.

Comment: Ah okay--since we parameterized $\theta$ by $r$, $\theta'$ becomes a function of $r$--got it.